# Remove or override eventListener with unknown handler

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way to remove or override an eventListener with an unknown handler? I did this by just setting a new addEventListener. This original handler opens an url. But I want to override this with a new handler that opens another url. This works fine in Chrome and Safari. But in IE this results in multiple new windows.

Comment: can you post some code? there's probably a good reason why this is happening

Comment: you can not override the eventListener, you need to remove it.

Comment: or add another one with a higher priority and use event.stopImmediatePropagation() (which looks dirty in this case though)

Comment: Sounds to me like a hack. This guy probably doesn't even have the source files.